# Unable to acess pip modules in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I installed `scikit-learn` via `pip3` but I can't access them in the jupyter notebook in the vs-code.
[image]

And when I am writing `!sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn` in a jupyter cell, i can't enter the password for `sudo`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python version in the terminal is **3.8** and according to the very lower left hand corner of the screenshot you posted, the version of Python that VSCode is running is **3.9.0**.

I'd recommend switching the version of Python that VSCode is running, by clicking on the version in the lower left hand corner of the VSCode window and selecting the one that matches the version in the terminal. That should solve it.